# How can I show the value of array with the Binary Search Tree of Comparison?

Tags: java

I going to do searching the value in the array, did I need to create a method to handle it? For example, the array logged 32,21,13,44,22, and I going to find 22 of the comparison. How can I implement this?

```
    public class binarySearch {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int i = binarySearch(0, new int[]{32,21,13,44,22});
        System.out.println("Iterations: " + i);
    }

    public static int binarySearch(int key, int[] array) {
        int left = 0;
        int mid;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (left <= right) {
            mid = (left + right) / 2;
            int comp = Integer.compare(key, array[mid]);
            i++;
            if (comp < 0) {
                right = mid - 1;
            } else if (comp > 0) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                break; // success
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

My final answer is here. May help you all in the future.

```
public static int binarySearch(int key, int[] array) {

        int left = 0;
        int mid;
        int right = array.length - 1;
        int i = 0;
        while (left <= right) {
            mid = (left + right) / 2;
            int comp = Integer.compare(key, array[mid]);
            i++;
            if (comp < 0) {
                right = mid - 1;
            } else if (comp > 0) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                break; // success
            }
        }
        return i;

    }
```

Comment: You question is unclear.  What do you want to display?

Comment: For example, the array logged 32,21,13,44,22, and I going to find 22 of the comparison.

Comment: "[F]ind 22 of the comparison..." is meaningless.  Are you saying you want to search for the value `22` in the array `32,21,13,44,22`? fo

Comment: may clearly, it may count the comparison, how many time compared can find 22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have *shuffled array*, all you can do is go through an array and find your number.

`BinarySearch` works **only** with **sorted** array. I think your solution could look like this:

```
public static int binarySearch(int[] arr, int key) {
    Arrays.sort(arr);
    return Arrays.binarySearch(arr, key);
}
```

Comment: how about I gave user choose or random choose one value in the array, and find the comparison?